# Are there any Simpler functions to fetch particular HTML node from the given input element?

Tags: c#, html, string, html-agility-pack, string-matching

Say My input is  Content  which is a sample and the tags may vary dynamically. Can I get the following outputs using Agility pack?

```
Output : 
 Tag - <td id="id34" class="dfg"> 
 ID- id34
 Class - Dfg
```

**EDIT:** By parsing the input string, I need to fetch the parameters . This can be achieved by writing a method .

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but if you `element.getElementsByTagName("div")` or `getElementById('id')` or `getElementsByClassName('classname')` you can get the element/s.

Comment: @delirium : Can we do it in a function or method in C#?

Comment: Wouldn't know, the code I suggested is in javascript, the language of the browser, did I misunderstand you then, I was under the impression that you want to fetch the elements that are in your HTML dom. Your post was edited, I no longer remember the structure.